# Need help to check and modify my SQL code which is aimed to find the next working date ( I wrote this code but got syntax error message, ask for help)

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE FUNCTION NewStartDate (startdate DATE)
RETURNS DATE DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

    DECLARE nextdate DATE;
    DECLARE counter integer;
    
    SET COUNTER = 0
    SET nextdate = startdate
    
    WHILE (nextdate in (select `dt` from `calendar2` where `IsHoliday`=1) LOOP
    
        nextdate = DATE_ADD(startdate,INTERVAL counter)
        counter=counter+1
        
    END LOOP
    
    RETURN nextdate;
END
```

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'loop nextdate = DATEADD(nextdate,counter); IF nextdate in (select `dt` FROM `c' at line 9

Comment: WHAT `syntax error message` ? Append it to the question. One thing is for sure, several terminating needs of `;` are missing, but that may not be the only issue ... and if you don't have a `DELIMITER` when creating that function will be trouble too.

Comment: I added the error message.

Comment: I am just curious how the systax checker could get you as far as the DATEADD function without hitting the wall before.  Clearly missing a couple of semicolons and a right parenthesis for the WHILE condition (and the syntax for your WHILE loop is dubious too ) should have brought up some error messages beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the code you provided have more than one syntax error. Notably, you did not specify the unit for the interval in your date_add function `DATE_ADD(startdate,INTERVAL counter)` . I have revised your code in workbench and tested it (using a different while condition). It works now.

```
delimiter //
drop function if exists NewStartDate//
CREATE FUNCTION NewStartDate (startdate DATE)
RETURNS DATE DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

    DECLARE nextdate DATE;
    DECLARE counter integer;
    
    SET COUNTER = 0 ;
    SET nextdate = startdate ;
    
    WHILE (nextdate in (select `dt` from `calendar2` where `IsHoliday`=1)) do
    
       set nextdate = DATE_ADD(startdate,INTERVAL + counter day);
       set counter=counter+1;
        
    END WHILE ;
    
    RETURN nextdate;
END //
```